# Splitting time and date in two separate date columns, in SQL server, is best practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Is it best practice to split a dateTime in two datetime SQL columns?

For example, 2010-12-17 01:55:00.000 is put in two colums,

- one column containing a datetime for
  the date portion:         2010-12-17 00:00:00.000
- one column containing a datetime
  for the time portion:     1900-01-01 01:55:00.000

I'm being told this is best practice because at some point SQL 2000 didn't allow to put time in a date? and that there are even data storage standards that enforce this and that some companies have ensure that all their data is stored in that manner to comply to some data storage standards?

If this is the case, I'm sure someone heard about it here, any of this sounds familiar?

Comment: At one point, it was also considered best practice to have 2 digits for years.

Comment: @Anthony - now was it considered **best** practice or was it just **common** practice?  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In sql server 2008 you have date and time data types so this becomes a non issue. datetime always allowed for time even back in sql server 6 and 7

the reason people split it up is because with everything in 1 column a query that returns all orders placed between 3 and 4 PM for any day requires a scan, with a time column this can be accomplished with a seek (much, much faster)

Comment: The scan vs seek I wasn't aware of, in my case, I would like to refactor a table that currently has each in datetime types. I thinking of bringing them either in a single datetime. Or as suggested here, the date in a date type, and time in a time type. The application is for time management, date and time are the core of the application.

Answer (score 4):

Starting in SQL 2005 I would do only one column.

If you wanted this information to be Sargable I would use [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) instead. This way you can query on date or time or both and your application code is only responsible for maintaining the one column.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but another reason you might want to keep separate is for user input (and GenEric said in a comment that this is for time management).  If you allow users to enter date/time as separate fields, and you want to be able to save the data with either field being empty, it is nice to have 2 separate null-able fields in your database.  Otherwise I guess you either have to resort to kludges where certain date values equal "empty" or add extra bit fields as "no time / no date" flags.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a scenario where a user would enter a time value that had no date context. In my experience this would normally be shorthand for assuming that the date was today, in which case the app would persist <today> + <time entered by user>. Can you provide an example where you would only want Time and not Date?